# r recognize and importing Multiple Tables from a Single excel file

Tags: r, parsing, extract

I tried to read all posts like this but I did not succeed.

I need to extract tables of different layouts from a single sheet in excel, for each sheet of the file.

Any help or ideas that can be provided would be greatly appreciated.

A sample of the datafile and it's structure can be found [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jh5UxWuvNVaY1qdFyL6JdnBMVjRig3ey/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do the locations of the tables stay the in every sheet?

Comment: every tables has the same headers but different length, based on the numbers of values in it. So location of the headers may shift up or down  in every sheet

Comment: do you need more info?

Comment: Maybe. I can see two ways of doing this. However, I think by far the easiest is to read the whole sheet in using the `readxl` package and initially labeling the columns with letters (and making sure each column is just a text column). Then hopefully you can locate the block of cells that forms each table from the sheet?

Comment: okay but how to labelling and locate?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `readxl`. The code below reads just one sheet, but it is easy enough to adapt to read multiple or different sheets.

First we just want to read the sheet. Obviously you should change the path to reflect where you saved your file:

```
library(readxl)
sheet = read_excel("~/Downloads/try.xlsx", col_names = LETTERS[1:12])
```

If you **didn't** know you had 12 columns, then using `read_excel` without specifying the column names would give you enough information to find that out. The different tables in the sheet are separated by one or two blank rows. You can find the blank rows by testing each row to see if all of the cells in that row are `NA` using the `apply` function.

```
blanks = which(apply(sheet, 1, function(row)all(is.na(row))))
blanks
```

```
> blanks
 [1]  7  8 17 26 35 41 50 59 65 74 80 86 95 98
```

So you could extract the first table by taking rows 1--6 (7 - 1), the second table by taking rows 9--16 and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you professor. Can I ask your help again? 

after extracting this, I would like to merge data and get a table like this one -->
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V7Zt5YCj-UYpT7zlow3lAflN952Y6M-seplD1132RBY/edit#gid=0

in which each selected row is the last one extracted.

Can you help me with this work?

Thanks